# Disabling required SSL ciphers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I recently have posted a web service for a client. They are now going through PCI DSS (I dont know what that is) and have had to disable medium strength SSL as well as SSLv3.

They are now asking if I can modify my service so that it doesn't require those ciphers.

**I don't really know what they are talking about. Can anyone give me some direction?**

Comment: PCI DSS are compliance requirements you need to pass if you handle customers' credit card data.

Answer (score 0):

PCI DSS 3.0 requires mandate TLS 1.2. SSl v3 is removed so the organization will not be PCI Compliant if they're using SSL v3.

PCI DSS is compliance that is needed by organization that deals with Card related information ( Credit Card / Debit Card etc ). It's mandatory to have PCI DSS Compliance for those organizations.

So basically, they're asking whether your service can support TLS 1.2 instead of older ciphers which are in SSL v3.